# Is any possible to custom split tooltip position?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**Expect**

shared series have independent position tooltip

**Tried**

According to the Highcharts document, I know the `Highcharts.tooltip.positioner` can make some custom to the tooltip, but while I search around, all of them are *un-split* tooltip. and failed in the split situation, so Is there any possible to custom split tooltip position?

http://jsfiddle.net/TabGre/fyxqsq4L/

**UPD**:

each point's tooltip just above it, just like `positioner`:

```
positioner: function () {
  return {
    x: this.plotX;
    y: this.plotY + 100;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "split"?

Comment: Positioner does not work with a split tooltip. You can use distance property: http://jsfiddle.net/zefz1u5e/1/ How exactly do you want to position the tooltip?

Comment: I have update my question ;smile;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, currently a positioner callback does not affect a split tooltip. However, it is possible to overwrite the function which is responsible for rendering a split tooltip. It requires calculating position on your own.

If you want a split tooltip to be in the top left corner as in your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyxqsq4L/3/)
you need to overwrite `Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype.renderSplit = function(labels, points)` with the desired position for each box.

```
  var yPos = 0;

            each(boxes, function(box, i) {
                var point = box.point,
                    series = point.series;

                // Put the label in place
                box.tt.attr({
                 //   visibility: box.pos === undefined ? 'hidden' : 'inherit',
                    x: (rightAligned || point.isHeader ?
                        //box.x :
                        0 :
                        point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + pick(options.distance, 16)),
                  //  y: box.pos + chart.plotTop,
                    y: yPos,
                    anchorX: point.isHeader ?
                        point.plotX + chart.plotLeft : point.plotX + series.xAxis.pos,
                    anchorY: point.isHeader ?
                        box.pos + chart.plotTop - 15 : point.plotY + series.yAxis.pos
                });
                yPos += box.size;
            });
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/tbguemvL/

Comment: Thanks for all you done, I will try my best to understand your code.